# replace space with comma in specific part of line

Tags: text-processing, sed

this is the output of a database query:

```
    1 KALI,REGISTERED
    2 KALI,PROCESSING
    3 KALI,RECEIVED
    1 KALI,SUBMITTED
    7 KALI,SUCCEEDED
    4 WEKA,PROCESSING
```

the output changes every time and maybe the number of lines differs from the last time that query is run but the format is always like this: `number space word,word`. i need them to be like this: `number,word,word`. i tried to handle this with query itself but database did't support this so i decided to handle this with Linux. i used this command to replace spaces with comma: `sed -e 's/\s\+/,/g' command.output`.i get this out put:

```
,1,KALI,REGISTERED,
,2,KALI,PROCESSING,
,3,KALI,RECEIVED,
,1,KALI,SUBMITTED,
,7,KALI,SUCCEEDED,
,4,WEKA,PROCESSING,
```

but i expect something like this so i can store it in an array:

```
1,KALI,REGISTERED
2,KALI,PROCESSING
3,KALI,RECEIVED
1,KALI,SUBMITTED
7,KALI,SUCCEEDED
4,WEKA,PROCESSING
```

tried a few more commands, none of them worked.how i can get this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you should change the database query to output the data in the format that you require.

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '{ $1 = $1; print }' file
1,KALI,REGISTERED
2,KALI,PROCESSING
3,KALI,RECEIVED
1,KALI,SUBMITTED
7,KALI,SUCCEEDED
4,WEKA,PROCESSING
```

This uses `awk` to reformat the space-or-tab-separated data as comma-separated.  By setting `OFS`, the output field separator, to a comma and by then modifying a field's value in each input record, `awk` will recreate the record with the new output separator. Printing it will give the wanted output.

`awk` also ignores any leading or trailing whitespace on each line when reading them, by default.

If you want to do this with `sed`, then first remove all initial whitespace, and then change the first remaining space to a comma:

```
$ sed -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' -e 's/[[:blank:]]/,/' file
1,KALI,REGISTERED
2,KALI,PROCESSING
3,KALI,RECEIVED
1,KALI,SUBMITTED
7,KALI,SUCCEEDED
4,WEKA,PROCESSING
```

The `[[:blank:]]` pattern matches a space or a tab (just like `\s` does in Perl's regular expressions). I'm using it out of habit, but you may want to use a single literal space instead, unless you are actually dealing with tabs (this is unclear in the question).  You can also write the two `sed` expressions in the same argument:

```
sed 's/^ *//; s/ /,/' file
```